# htaccess password protected directory and mod_rewrite RerwriteCond

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, password-protection

I have a site that i want to redirect all requests accept for 1 directory path.

http://mysite.com/application
http://mysite.com/application/templates
http://mysite.com/application/admin  (password protected)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/application
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://mynewsite.com [R=307]
```

My rewrite engine on the `.htaccess` is working fine, except when accessing the /admin directory which is password protected.  When i try to request it, i am redirected.  If i rename the `.htaccess` in the `/admin` folder. it works fine.  My suspicion is that the browser (FF) is requesting another url which matches the redirect.  How can i keep the directory password protected, but not redirect?

Comment: Firebug (https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/firebug/) would help you verify your assumption. However, I have setup a test server matching your configuration, and it works fine here. Something else must be kicking in.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I couldn't quickly get firebug to work, but i'd imagine it might or might not have shown me what was happening if the redirect was hitting the rule before getting sent back to the browser.  You did help get me to start thinking on other approaches, so thanks for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

by adding:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !401
```

Now it works.  I believe this is due to the shared webhost configuration which has pre-assigned 4XX and 5XX page redirects.  So, that that is what was happening.  The !401 isn't perfect, but for my simple app it works.  I think something like this would be better to capture 401 as the beginning of the uri (pattern is untested):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/401
```

Comment: Thanks this fixed my issue as well. I was trying to password protect a dir using while using mod_rewrite but for some reason it was ignoring RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d rule. This fixed it though. Cheers